# Create Doctrine Object by ID without Details from Database Lookup

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

Each **Question** object of mine is mapped to a **Category** object, but I'm attaching the object via AJAX call, so I only know the Category ID when creating the **Question**, meaning I have do a database read to get the entire **Category** object.

Can I attach the **Category** to the **Question** without having to reach into the database and instantiate the entire **Category** object?  I'm looking to avoid that database lookup...

Working code I'm looking to streamline:

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();  
$category = $entityManager->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Category')->find($categoryId);

$question = new Question();
...
$question->setCategory($category);
$entityManager->persist($question);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a reference instead.   No query needed.

```
$category = $entityManager->getReference('AcmeBundle:Category',$categoryId);
```